# GitHub repo on VisualSVN Server

Tags: git, svn, github, visualsvn-server

We have a Github repo that is connected to our live server online. To manage code internally, we have a Staging server with VisualSVN server to which the team commits the code and then if all is fine, commits to Github.

I did the followsing steps and have the subsequent issue. Please let me know if I'm missing something :

1. Create a repo and checked out the Github repository
2. The files got imported within Trunk.
3. But when I open VisualSVN and browse the repo, it shows an empty repo on browser and also while one checks out this repo internally, it shows an empty repo as well.
4. On the file system, all files under trunk are shown tracked (obviously with Github) and are visible.

Edit from the comment:

> I created an empty repo on Visual SVN and using SVN Checkout on
>   TortoiseSVN and provided the Github Repo's URL in it. The files got
>   imported into Trunk. I can view the files directly on the Folder. But
>   when I go back and Browse on Visual SVN it shows an empty repo.

I understand that while the github is in sync, I'm missing somewhere on creating a SVN repository locally perhaps? Any pointers to fix this would be of great help.

Comment: It's unclear how you do the import and how you checkout the svn repo. Please elaborate these steps. BTW, run `svn log` against the repo and see the result.

Comment: I created an empty repo on Visual SVN and using SVN Checkout on TortoiseSVN and provided the Github Repo's URL in it. The files got imported into Trunk. I can view the files directly on the Folder. But when I go back and Browse on Visual SVN it shows an empty repo.

Comment: you are doing it wrong from the very beginning.

Comment: ok I could see that. So what is the right way to do this?

Comment: Thank you. My need is pretty simple. I have a github repo that I don't want the team to commit seperately. We run VisualSVN on a server and we would like all commits by the team to be written into this, which would then commit to GitHub.

Comment: Why was the most crucial comment deleted???